# Entity Framework getting confused about navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.1 and I have a `Users` table and a `User_Documents` table (1:many). I already had a navigation property from `User_Documents` to `User` were things were working fine.

```
public partial class User_Document
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long User_Document_ID { get; set; }

    public long User_ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User_ID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

I added a navigation property from Users to User_Documents

```
public partial class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long User_ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public virtual List<User_Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

and now I'm getting an error when I try to run the application:

> System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: One or
>   more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> User_Documents: Name: Each member name in an EntityContainer must be
>   unique. A member with name 'User_Documents' is already defined.

Of course there is a table called `User_Documents` but no other property with that name. I'm not sure what's it getting confused by. Maybe it's taking the table name "User" and the property name "Documents" and trying to create something called "User_Documents" out of it? If I rename it to from `Documents` 
to `Some_Documents` like this

```
public virtual List<User_Document> Some_Documents { get; set; }
```

then I get a different error stating

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model backing the
>   'PipeTrackerContext' context has changed since the database was
>   created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database

So I run `Add-Migration` and I get this:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.User_Documents", "User_User_ID", c => c.Long());
    CreateIndex("dbo.User_Documents", "User_User_ID");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.User_Documents", "User_User_ID", "dbo.Users", "User_ID");
}
```

Why is it trying to add a new column called `User_User_ID`? Why can't I just add the `Document` navigation property like I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use InverseProperty Like this :

```
public partial class User_Document
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long User_Document_ID { get; set; }

    public long User_ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User_ID")]
    [InverseProperty("Documents")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

And :

```
public partial class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long User_ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual List<User_Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what problem is solved and how this solves it?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it trying to add a new column called User_User_ID? Why can't I
>   just add the Document navigation property like I want?

By convention, it will create the foreign key as **`tablename_columnName`** which is `User_User_ID`. This happens when you remove the `[ForeignKey("User_ID")]` attribute OR don't have foreign key property.

If you change the property name `Documents` to something else (like`UserDocuments`) you wont face this conflict of names.

Comment: Right, but if I rename Documents to UserDocuments, it still wants to add a field called User_User_ID to the Users table. Why is that?

Comment: Nope. Adding of User_User_ID is related to the foreign key attribute. Do you have the attribute or you have removed it ?

Comment: It looks just like the code I posted. The User property in the User_Documents table does have the [ForeignKey] attribute on it.