# Why is Entity Framework creating an extra column that doesn't map to any field and is always null?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have my POCO set up like this:

```
public class Notification : BaseClass
{

    public User Receiver { get; set; }

    [Required, Index]
    public long ReceiverID { get; set; }

    public virtual User ContextualUser { get; set; }

    public long? ContextualUserID { get; set; }

    public virtual User Actor { get; set; }

    public long? ActorID { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public string Uri { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Type { get; set; }

}
```

My base class has *only* three properties: `ID`, `CreateDate`, and `IsDeleted`, none are related to `User` class:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public BaseClass()
    {
        CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

However, Entity Framework creates an extra column, `User_ID`, which is *always null*, as seen below:

[image]

It doesn't apparently map to anything. None of my other entities (either deriving from the same base class or not) have this *phantom* column. Why is this column created? I am on EF 6.1.3 code-first with SQL Azure.

**UPDATE:** I've also ran `update-database` in PM console but nothing has changed, I still have this column.

**UPDATE 2:** There is even an index and a foreign key defined on column. I've tried dropping it (it's not a live app yet) but it's being referenced by an index:

`alter table notifications drop column User_ID`

```
Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The index 'IX_User_ID' is dependent on column 'User_ID'.
Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The object 'FK_dbo.Notifications_dbo.Users_User_ID' is dependent on column 'User_ID'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN User_ID failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

Comment: @FabioLuz I am dead sure. it has only the three properties that I've said: ID, CreateDate, IsDeleted. that's it. Just re-checked to make sure.

Comment: Do you have a mapping class (using FluentAPI) ?

Comment: @FabioLuz no. I'm not using Fluent API anywhere in my application. I'm all-annotation in that sense.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu how does your base class look like? also , are you using EF migrations, there could be a column being added there for some reason.

Comment: @SOfanatic I've also added the code for my base class to avoid confusion. I've used EF migrations (none of them were explicit, only implicit), but ran `update-database` after each migration, and ran it again just now to be sure.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu create a new database, change the EF's database target to the new database. Then, create a new migration and see if the User_ID column is there

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu not sure if this could be it, but the `User Receiver` property is missing the `virtual` keyword

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu I'm afraid that the `User_ID` is the foreign key of one of the `User` properties. Try to set the foreign key explicitly. Like this: `[ForeignKey("ContextualUserID")]` `[ForeignKey("ActorID")]` and `[Receiver("ReceiverID")]`. You can put theses attributes on top of the `User` properties

Comment: @FabioLuz it was navigation property on my **User** class configured incorrectly. because `Notification` didn't have a property called `User` but rather `Receiver`, I've forgot to add the correct name (Receiver) as an inverse property on my User class' `Notifications` collection. I've added the annotation ` [InverseProperty("Receiver")]` and it now works correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was navigation property on my `User` class configured incorrectly. Because `Notification` class didn't have a property called `User` but rather `Receiver`, and because I've forgot to add the correct name (Receiver) as an inverse property on my `User` class which had a `Notifications` collection, this extra field was generated for navigating *from* `User` *to* `Notification`s. I've added the annotation `[InverseProperty("Receiver")]` to my collection on `User` class and it now works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use data annonations for this :

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public BaseClass()
    {
        CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}

public class Notification : BaseClass
{
    [ForeignKey("ReceiverID")]
    [InverseProperty("Receivers")]
    public User Receiver { get; set; }

    [Required, Index]
    public long ReceiverID { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("ContextualUserID")]
    [InverseProperty("ContextualUsers")]
    public virtual User ContextualUser { get; set; }

    public long? ContextualUserID { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("ActorID")]
    [InverseProperty("Actors")]
    public virtual User Actor { get; set; }

    public long? ActorID { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public string Uri { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Type { get; set; }

}

public class User
{
    [InverseProperty("Receiver")]
    public ICollection<Notification> Receivers { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ContextualUser")]
    public ICollection<Notification> ContextualUsers { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Actor")]
    public ICollection<Notification> Actors { get; set; }
}
```

for more information :

[Many to many relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831729/asp-net-mvc-many-to-many-relationship-using-my-own-table/29832776#29832776)

[Navigation property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721471/entity-framework-getting-confused-about-navigation-property/29721642#29721642)